# Parse xml with namespaces via dom4j XPath strange behaviour

Tags: java, xml, xpath

The problem is - when I parse an XML with namespaces through XPath it parses XML partly, for example if I set to XPath: /SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body - parser recognize this good, but if I go further - parser crushes without returning exception.

This is an XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m0="http://schemas.compassplus.com/two/1.0/fimi.xsd"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.compassplus.com/two/1.0/fimi.wsdl">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<m:GetAcctInfoRp xmlns:m="http://schemas.compassplus.com/two/1.0/fimi.xsd">
<Response Response="1" Product="FIMI" Ver="0"><m0:Avail>995526.4</m0:Avail>
<m0:Bonus>0</m0:Bonus>
<m0:Branch>1</m0:Branch>
<m0:Cards><m0:Row>
<m0:PAN>6706250002450356</m0:PAN>
<m0:MBR>0</m0:MBR>
<m0:CardUID>E4BFBC24A2844F13BE5C5AEEB15D27CE</m0:CardUID>
<m0:Status>1</m0:Status>
</m0:Row>
<m0:Row>
<m0:PAN>6706255660781224</m0:PAN>
<m0:MBR>0</m0:MBR>
<m0:CardUID>971111C18D774C3BA26434336CB57475</m0:CardUID>
<m0:Status>1</m0:Status>
</m0:Row>
</m0:Cards>
<m0:CreditHold>0</m0:CreditHold>
<m0:Currency>810</m0:Currency>
<m0:DebitHold>50240.81</m0:DebitHold>
<m0:DropTmpOverOnRefresh>0</m0:DropTmpOverOnRefresh>
<m0:FoundAccount>40817810200001058114</m0:FoundAccount>
<m0:FoundAccountUID>E79459BEEEF94BEFBA57D0D23503EF7E</m0:FoundAccountUID>
<m0:LastDepAmount>10</m0:LastDepAmount>
<m0:LastDepTime>2012-03-06T17:23:35</m0:LastDepTime>
<m0:LastRefreshTime>2012-02-22T12:49:47</m0:LastRefreshTime>
<m0:LastTranId>4172</m0:LastTranId>
<m0:LastWdlAmount>100</m0:LastWdlAmount>
<m0:LastWdlTime>2012-03-06T17:29:44</m0:LastWdlTime>
<m0:Ledger>1045767.21</m0:Ledger>
<m0:MaskBalances>0</m0:MaskBalances>
<m0:Overdraft>9000000</m0:Overdraft>
<m0:PersonExtId>1891</m0:PersonExtId>
<m0:PersonFIO>bla bla bla</m0:PersonFIO>
<m0:PersonId>782</m0:PersonId>
<m0:Remain>1046068.21</m0:Remain>
<m0:Status>3</m0:Status>
<m0:TmpOverdraft>0</m0:TmpOverdraft>
<m0:Type>1</m0:Type>
<m0:UserFields><m0:Row>
<m0:Name>test</m0:Name>
<m0:TextValue>тест</m0:TextValue>
</m0:Row>
</m0:UserFields>
</Response>
</m:GetAcctInfoRp>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Java code that should parse this XML file:

```
String res = RequestMethods.executeXMLPostRequest(url, xml);
Document doc = DocumentHelper.parseText(res.trim());

        String session = doc.valueOf("SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/m:GetAcctInfoRp/Response/m0:Avail");
```

PS sorry for my English, may be someone solved this problem yet?
Please help.

THe 1-st issue is solved, another question is - how can I get in cycled structure, for example if We have several SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body//m0:Avail elements?

Comment: Which library are you using? (Could you elaborate on the Document and DocumentHelper classes you are using? What is the full class name with package name?)

Comment: As U can see in this title the library is dom4j, package - import org.dom4j.*;

Comment: thanks, I did not notice the lib in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {
    String xmlText = getContents(new File("/home/bpgergo/Temp/9682103.xml"));
    Document doc = DocumentHelper.parseText(xmlText);
    String session = doc.valueOf("SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body//m0:Avail");
    System.out.println("session:"+session);
}
```

Comment: this also works `String session = doc.valueOf("SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body//Response/m0:Avail");` If I include `m:GetAcctInfoRp` in the path, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Duuuuuuude U've saved my aaaaaasssss =) Thank U very much, I gave U a point and accept Your answer, thanks man.

Comment: And another question is how can I get in cycled structure, for example if We have several SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body//m0:Avail elements? Pleeeeeeeese =)

Comment: Everythings ok - just made selectNodes casted them to array of Elements and then took text from every element - done.